# how do you debug your facebook app?

Tags: debugging, facebook, web-applications, canvas

facebook php developing app is hell cause they limit scripts, what is your tools to debug it? write to file variables? firebug? please share ideas!

Answer (score 2):

Debugging facebook application is almost the same as any web application:
Client Side:

- Debugging the JS library online, [JavaScript Test Console](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/console)
- Firebug (`console.` method)

Server Side:

- Firebug `Net` tab and FirePHP (if you feel comfortable using it)
- basic `var_dump` and `echo` commands

What I really find hard to grasp is their documentation!

**Extra tip**:
Try playing around with the [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/) methods, creating a test group/page and events..etc to better understand how FB Graph API works. It'll make reading the Documentation easier too!